# How to transfer "this" in onreadystatechange with an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I use AJAX to post data to the server, I want to use `this` in the `onreadystatechange` function.
For example:

**HTML**

```
<div onclick=send.call(this)></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function send () {
    this.style.background = "#ccc";
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("post", "/post.php", true);
    xml.send("data");
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            this.style.background = "#fff";
        }
    }.call(this);
}
```

I think it works, but when I use `call`, the `onreadystatechange` function only run once. When I use the code such as:

```
xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(xml.state);
}
```

the output is: `1 2 3 4`, but when I use

```
xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(xml.state);
}.call(this)
```

the output is: `1` Why?

Comment: `call` !== `bind`

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: ;)thanks,now i know what's the wrong